# Get URL of YouTube live stream

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

How to find out which video ID (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID) corresponds to current live stream available at URL like this: https://www.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID/live ?

The software available is:

- youtube-dl (yt-dlp)
- streamlink
- shell in CentOS